# Wordpress CSS Confusion

Tags: css, wordpress

Good morning,

I am creating my 1st Wordpress theme from scratch and I have hit my 1st barrier.

If you take a look at my progress so far;

```
http://www.trevorpeters.co.uk/brad/?page_id=4
```

You will see that the CSS is linked correctly, but the H1 tag and P tag are not taking all of the attributes from the defined style, In Mozilla Firefox dev tools, some of the attributes are crossed out but are NOT being overwritten by any other styles.

Thanks, Brad Houston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styles get overridden by `reset.css line 92`. You can have a look at `computed styles` in the dev tools to have a look which style finally is applied to your element and the name of the source this style comes from. This is very handy when there are a lot of styles overriding each other.

You need to switch the order of your `style.css` and `reset.css` and then everything should be fine, because now your stylesheet overrides the default settings of the `reset.css`.

Answer (score 1):

your style.css is above your reset.css.. what you do expect?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.trevorpeters.co.uk/brad/wp-content/themes/andromeda/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.trevorpeters.co.uk/brad/wp-content/themes/andromeda/css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.trevorpeters.co.uk/brad/wp-content/themes/andromeda/css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.trevorpeters.co.uk/brad/wp-content/themes/andromeda/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

check your header.php for the codes...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've placed the CSS-files in the wrong order.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.trevorpeters.co.uk/brad/wp-content/themes/andromeda/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.trevorpeters.co.uk/brad/wp-content/themes/andromeda/css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

You reset your style after style.css.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reorder the css stylesheets.  You're putting the reset.css after the style.css so the reset is overlapping the style.